# Using browser back button to navigate between the website pages

Tags: asp.net

I have search this but didn't get useful information. In my website I have a order processing scenario. currently I am using a "back" button on page to go to the previous order page. I want to go back through the browser back button. I want the code which I added in page back button can run when I use the browser back button.
How I achieve this..?

Comment: **window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost."; };**
this is the function where javascript will be executed before unload you can put your code here

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
});
});
```

here the link is the one on which click you want to go back

or even better
 have a look at this

[`History.go`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history#go) can do that:

```
parent.history.go(-1);
```